# Change URL structure from /blog-post.php?id_blog_post=852 to something like /unblur-course-hero

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

How can I change

```
/blog-post.php?id_blog_post=852
```

to

```
/unblur-course-hero
```

which is the title of the page.

I need a proper URL structure without `_?/` etc

Comment: Please upload with proper screenshot

Comment: You have to store this value: `unblur-course-hero` in your DB record as a `slug` with id of this post equal to `852`, after that you can check in your controller if there is any record with `slug` value equal to requested, and return html if exist such record.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store this value: `unblur-course-hero` in your DB record as a `slug` with id of this post equal to `852`, after that you can check in your controller if there is any record with `slug` value equal to requested, and return html if exist such record. 
Example:
**Request:**

```
/blog-post.php?id_blog_post=852
```

**URL you have to create:**

```
/unblur-course-hero
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index($slug = false){
   if($slug){
       //we have slug here, we search for record, overwise skip
       //query to check DB where `slug` = $slug
       //DO NOT FORGET TO USE BEST PRACTICES TO BIND VALUES while you make any 
       //searches using public requests. 
   }
   //perform regular index page rendering.
}
```